# Swift - Add UITableViewCell programmatically don't work properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have this code:

```
class Cell:UITableViewCell {
    var fullName:UILabel! = UILabel()
    var userImage:UIImage! = UIImage()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        println("wake")
        fullName.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        contentView.addSubview(fullName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: userImage)
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        var viewsDict = [
            "fullName" : fullName,
            "userImage" : userImage
        ]

        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[userImage(10)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[fullName]-[userImage(10)]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    }
}
```

viewDidLoad:

```
var tableView = UITableView()
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height-64)
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
var cell = Cell.self
tableView.registerClass(cell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

cellForRowAtIndexpath:

```
let cell:Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell
cell.fullName.text = testarray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
return cell
```

I can't see the label in the cell when I execute the code even println("wake") in class Cell is not executed.

Comment: When you said programatically creation of cell. Then `awakeFromNib()` method not comes in a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom `UITableViewCell` should be like below code:

```
class ListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var lblTitle = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        lblTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
        lblTitle.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18.0)
        lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        lblTitle.numberOfLines = 1
        lblTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        lblTitle.textColor = UIColor(red: 130/255, green: 137/255, blue: 141/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.lblTitle)
        // 130 137 141
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 0, right: -100)

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        var marginX = CGFloat(30.0)
        var marginY = CGFloat(0.0)
        var width = CGFloat(320)
        var height = self.contentView.frame.size.height

        self.lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(marginX, marginY, width, height)
    }

}
```

And this is how you can create cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView` datasource.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:ListTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellIdentifier) as? ListTableViewCell

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = ListTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)
        }
        cell.lblTitle.text = self.listItems[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: The second part of your answer is not needed - there's nothing wrong with the dequeuing in the question.

Comment: I provided complete code, So in future it help others too.

Answer (score 0):

`awakeFromNib` is only called when an object is loaded from a nib or storyboard. You're not doing that, since a class is registered.

You need to move that code to the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` method as mentioned in the UITableView docs for the dequeue method:

> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file